# Is it possible to color the whole components not the border of them if I'm dealing with countours?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

**What i want:** I am detecting the contours in an image. After that i want to fill the whole object (who's contour has been detected) by white color.

**Problem:** `drawContour()` only draws a boundary around the detected contour but what i need is to fill the whole object with white color not just the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

```
drawContours(InputOutputArray image, InputArrayOfArrays contours, int contourIdx, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, InputArray hierarchy=noArray(), int maxLevel=INT_MAX, Point offset=Point() )
```

instead of 1, replace the thickness with CV_FILLED

```
int thickness=CV_FILLED
```

Comment: I'm using cvDrawContours not drawContours

Comment: still, the answer stands same, replace the thickness part, instead of 1 with the above mentioned snippet